# Simplify a series of repetitive functions with sort options

Tags: python, revit-api, pyrevit

I have a series of functions in a module which are starting to become quite repetitive. Each function extracts a list, and has an optional boolean argument to sort the list before returning it. Feels like there ought to be a way to inherit the sorting from a parent function?

```
def get_electrical_equipment(sort_by_name = False):
    
    elements =  DB.FilteredElementCollector(revit.doc)\
        .OfCategory(DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_ElectricalEquipment)\
        .WhereElementIsNotElementType()\
        .ToElements()
        
    if sort_by_name: elements.sort(key=lambda x: x.Name)
    
    return elements

def get_panel_schedules(sort_by_name = False):
    elements = DB.FilteredElementCollector(revit.doc)\
        .WherePasses(DB.ElementClassFilter(DB.Electrical.PanelScheduleView))\
        .WhereElementIsNotElementType()\
        .ToElements()
        
    if sort_by_name: elements.sort(key=lambda x: x.Name)
    
    return elements

def get_panel_schedule_sheet_instances(sort_by_name = False):
    elements = DB.FilteredElementCollector(revit.doc)\
        .OfClass(DB.Electrical.PanelScheduleSheetInstance)\
        .ToElements()
        
    if sort_by_name: elements.sort(key=lambda x: x.Name)
    
    return elements
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you can completely eliminate the call to `ToElements`. It is a waste of memory and computation time, as I have pointed out about 500 times in the past in the Revit API discussion forum and in The Building Coder, e.g., in [How to Distinguish Redundant Rooms](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/04/how-to-distinguish-redundant-rooms.html#2). Now, to address your question, you can simply implement a common method `get_elements_of_category_and_class` taking a category and a class argument. Pass in either one or the other or both and execute `OfClass` and `OfCategory` checks on the filtered element collector, either one or the other or both, skipping evaluation of `null`-valued arguments.